# Array of ManualResetEvent objects

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, synchronization

here's my story: I have wcf service. It receives request with work to do. Each task is inserted into blocking queue. The server will take items from this queue periodically and do the work (totally async in different thread). In my "Do" service I need to know when "my" task was done. Like this:

```
    public bool Do(int input)
    {
        // 1. Add task to the BlockingCollection queue
        // 2. Block this thread from returning and observe/wait til my task is finished
        return true;
    }
```

Here's my suggestion/solution:

```
    public bool Do(int input)
    {
        // 1. Create a ManualResetEvent object
        // 2. Add this object to task
        // 3. Add task to the BlockingCollection queue
        // 4. Block this thread from returning - wait for ManualResetEvent object
        return true;
    }
```

So, there will be as many ManualResetEvent objects as there are tasks to do. I will literally have an array of sync objects. Is it good solution for my problem?

Or is there better synchronization class to use in my case? Like Wait and Pulse?

Thanks for help,

I'm sorry for the title. I didn't know how to ask this question in the title.

Comment: Make a class State object  for each task and create a List<State>.  Put properties like time and id into the State as well as the thread object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plan is good, however I would suggest not tying up a dedicated thread waiting for the work to be done. Switching from a `new ManualResetEvent(false)` to a `new SemephoreSlim(0,1)` will let you use `WaitAsync()` which would allow you to use async/await in your `Do` method and freeing up the thread to do other work. (UPDATE: This really should be a `TaskCompletionSource` instead of a Semaphore Slim, but I will not update this example, see the 2nd part below)

```
public async Task<bool> Do(int input)
{
    using(var completion = new new SemephoreSlim(0,1))
    {
        var job = new JobTask(input, completion);
        _workQueue.Add(job);
        await completion.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return job.ResultData;
    }
}

private void ProcessingLoop()
{
    foreach(var job in _workQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        job.PerformWork(); //Inside PerformWork there is a _completion.Release(); call.
    }
}
```

---

To make everything self contained you can change the `SemaphoreSlim` / `TaskCompletionSource` and put it inside the job then just return the job itself.

```
    public JobTask Do(int input)
    {
        var job = new JobTask(input);
        _workQueue.Add(job);
        return job;
    }

public class JobTask
{
    private readonly int _input;
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> _completionSource;

    public JobTask(int input)
    {
        _input = input;
        _completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    }

    public void PerformWork()
    {
        try
        {
            // Do stuff here with _input.

            _completionSource.TrySetResult(true);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _completionSource.TrySetException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Task<bool> Work { get { return _completionSource.Task; } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott, but why I would do "Do" async? The "Do" function just adds an item (a single "int" to be specific) to the queue and returns... nothing more. Server periodically takes a batch of tasks and "do them". After "Add to the queue" I need to wait for this particular "id" to be done.

Comment: I assumed `Do` did not always return `true` I thought that `true` was coming from the work that was done so you would need to have done a `.WaitOne()` with your old `ManualResetEvent` in the old code in the `Do` method. If that returned bool was not from the work job just make it return `void`. I will update my answer with a example that way.

Comment: thanks. I added `return true` so the wcf client could receive response when the job (for his id) is done on the server.

Comment: I did not notice this was WCF, you might want to look in to using duplex callback methods for WCF, that is much better suited for long running operations you are waiting to complete.

Comment: Oh, I read about duplex and indeed it's a better way to do it. Will your answer be different if it's duplex wcf service ?

Comment: Not too diffrent, it basicly would be my original SemaphoreSlim answer but instead of passing in a SemaphoreSlim I would do `var job = new JobTask(input, OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IJobCallback>());` then the `IJobCallback` has some function called at the end of `PerformWork()`.